# Official Practice and Patterns Microsoft documentation for Enterprise .net applications?

Tags: .net, documentation

Where can I find Official Practice and Patterns Microsoft documentation for Enterprise .net applications?

I find small pieces all over the place, the only one I can find is from 2003.

I find very hard to find the official documentation of Practice and Patterns, am I the only one?

something like this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998469.aspx?rssCatalog

Comment: A comment as only related to you question http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried looking at the Microsoft Patterns and Practices website?

Their complete documentation catalog is [online here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/practices/bb190351)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not quite sure what you're asking, but perhaps you're looking for the Enterprise Library Framework?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648951.aspx